# Can't boot Ubuntu 16.04.2 LTS after installing it

Tags: boot, dual-boot, grub2, uefi

I have a UEFI windows 10 machine an I'm trying to dual boot ubuntu. At first I got the error: "grub-efi-amd64-signed failed to install into /target/. Without GRUB boot loader, the installed system will not boot". But I solved that by making a 100MB EFI partition and Ubuntu finished its installation.

Now I don't see a boot menu; I can't use EasyBCD to add Ubuntu to the boot menu; I don't see any options in msconfig menu. And boot-repair did nothing for me!

boot-info: https://pastebin.com/tGuH2GvL

I don't know if it is relevant, but originally I installed windows in legacy and than converted to UEFI using this [YouTube video guide](https://youtu.be/Aewp3nbjY5c)

Answer (score 1):

It looks like your system uses an NVMe disk, which means your Boot Info Script output is somewhat lacking; however, there's enough information that I can be pretty confident that your problem is caused by the `ubuntu` boot entry not being in the boot order. To fix it, try these steps:

1. Your `efibootmgr` output (lines 258-271 of the Boot Info Script output) indicates that Windows is first in the boot order. You might be able to move the `ubuntu` entry to the top of the boot order by using [EasyUEFI](http://www.easyuefi.com/index-us.html) in Windows or `efibootmgr` in Ubuntu. (Type `sudo efibootmgr -o 0000,0002,0003,2001,2002,2003` to add Ubuntu to the start of the boot list.)
2. If you can't adjust the boot order, you might want to try using your firmware's setup utility to reset all the firmware options to their defaults. This may wipe the existing Ubuntu entry, which you'd need to re-create; but it's possible it would enable you to set the boot order when you try again.
3. If resetting the firmware fails, then chances are your firmware is defective. If possible, my recommendation at this point is to return the computer for a refund and buy one that works. If that's not possible, there are ugly workarounds, like renaming GRUB/Shim so that it's launched in place of the Windows boot loader, and moving the Windows boot loader to another location. The [Boot Repair utility](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Boot-Repair) can do this semi-automatically by using an option to back up and rename boot loader files on its Advanced menu.